# I want to print the string equivalent to the number entered by the user, but it just takes an input from the user and exits the program

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop, pointers

For example, if I have entered the value of (5) to be stored in n variable, All I want to print the equivalent string which is "five", but it does not make that

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
    char *between_[10]={"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if( n == *(between_+i) )
        {
            printf("%s", between_[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to print the equivalent string

Comment: `*(between_+i)`, is equivalent to `between_[i]`. The latter is easier to understand and is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a loop. You can't compare an input number with a string meaningfully.

Check that `n` is between 1 and 9. Then print the corresponding element of the array.

```
if (n >= 1 && n <= 9) {
    printf("%s\n", between_[n-1]);
}
```

You need to subtract 1 because array indexes start at 0.